# java Map removal unexpected behavior

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, awt

code:

```
public class FeatureBuilder implements IFeatureBuilder {

   private final Map< java.awt.Shape, ShapeAttributes > shapes = new HashMap<>();

   [...]

   @Override
   public void addToContainer( java.awt.Shape shape ) {
      System.err.println( shape.getClass());
      shapes.put( shape, new ShapeAttributes( ... ));
   }

   @Override
   public void removeFromContainer( double x, double y ) {
      final Set< Shape > rm  = new HashSet<>();
      final Point2D      loc = new Point2D.Double( x, y );
      for( final Shape shape : shapes.keySet()) {
         if( shape.contains( loc )) {
            System.err.println( "shapes.containsKey( shape ): " +
               shapes.containsKey( shape ));
            rm.add( shape );
         }
      }
      System.err.println( "cardinality before removal : " + shapes.size());
      shapes.keySet().removeAll( rm );
      System.err.println( "cardinality after  removal : " + shapes.size());
   }
```

output:

```
class java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double
shapes.containsKey( shape ): false      <<<<<<< This is unexpected!
cardinality before removal : 1
rm cardinality             : 1
cardinality after  removal : 1
```

I'm surprised: an instance retrieved by a `for` iterator on `Map.keySet()` is not a key in the `Map`!

How is this possible?

The main bug in this method is the selected instances of Shape placed in `rm` are not removed from `shapes`.

**After reading your answers the code becomes:**

```
public class DecoratedShape {

   public final Shape _shape;
   public /* */ Color _stroke      = Color.BLACK;
   public /* */ float _strokeWidth = 3.0f;
   public /* */ Color _fill        = Color.BLACK;

   public DecoratedShape( Shape shape, Color stroke, float strokeWidth, Color fill ) {
      _shape       = shape;
      _stroke      = stroke;
      _strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
      _fill        = fill;
   }

   public boolean contains( Point2D loc ) {
      return _shape.contains( loc );
   }

   public void paint( Graphics2D g ) {
      g.setStroke( new BasicStroke( _strokeWidth ));
      g.setColor( _fill );
      g.fill( _shape );
      g.setColor( _stroke );
      g.draw( _shape );
   }
}

public class FeatureBuilder implements IFeatureBuilder {

   private final List< DecoratedShape > _shapes = new LinkedList<>();
   [...]

   @Override
   public void addToContainer( Object o ) {
      _shapes.add( new DecoratedShape((Shape)o, _stroke, _strokeWidth, _fill ));
   }

   @Override
   public void removeFromContainer( double x, double y ) {
      final Set<DecoratedShape> rm = new HashSet<>();
      final Point2D loc = new Point2D.Double( x, y );
      for( final DecoratedShape shape : _shapes ){
         if( shape.contains( loc ) ){
            rm.add( shape );
         }
      }
      _shapes.removeAll( rm );
   }

   public void paint( Graphics2D g ) {
      for( final DecoratedShape shape : _shapes ) {
         shape.paint( g );
      }
   }
}
```

And now, it works as expected... Thanks a lot!

Comment: This typically happens when the equals and hashcode method are not consistent. However it does not seem to be the case for `Rectangle2D`...

Comment: Can you give a SSCCE (i.e. create an instance of Rectangle2D.Double that reproduces the behaviour)?

Comment: Maybe some more debugging information such as printing out the `hashcode()` would be helpful to compare the two and whether `equals()` returns true.

Comment: First of all, you should not use a mutable object as key in your `HashMap`. I guess this is what creating the issue here. But we need more code to crack this.

Comment: @RohitJain of course, that's it: it is mutable and probably gets mutated between being added to the map and the method in the question. That is most likely the answer.

Comment: Yes, the shapes are mutated after insertion. They are resized by mouse drag. The choice of the Map is a mistake. The true need is to add some properties to the standard swing Shape. I'm going to replace the Map<Shape,ShapeAttributes> by a List<DecoratedShape>.

Comment: @Aubin You could extend the shapes you are interested in and give them a name or id that does not change when they get resized. Or even better, define your own `ShapeHolder` than has a Shape and a String/Integer id. You could then use that ID as a key to your map. Otherwise it will be a tricky exercise.

Comment: The Map was used to associate information to an instance. The notion of "key" isn't needed. A simple List with a true object is more easy to use as shown in the second part of the edited post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following-up on @RohitJain's comment, here is a simple example that reproduces the behaviour:

```
Map<Shape, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double shape = new java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double(1, 1, 1, 1);
map.put(shape, null);
System.out.println(map.size()); //1
shape.setRect(2, 2, 2, 2); //mutate
System.out.println(map.size()); //still 1
map.keySet().remove(shape);
System.out.println(map.size()); //still 1
```

The underlying problem is that the Shape is mutated while in the map.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about the `false` output from the `for` loop. Can that be possible? Because the `shape` is getting fetched from the map only. Strange :(

Comment: Yes that's possible.  The keySet is a simple iterator that will show all contents.  When you go back with containsKey it will hash and look in the 'wrong' bucket.

Comment: @Affe Oh! Great. Don't know how I missed that. `containsKey` recalculates the `hash` value, and it differs from the earlier one.

Comment: +1: your answer is good. But a question remains about the eligibility of Shape (more precisely Rectangle2D) as a key into a Map... Lesson learn today!

Comment: @Aubin Generally speaking, it is not recommended to use mutable keys, and if you do you need to make sure you never mutate them. You can find more about it in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html): "*Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.*"

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't explain why your code doesn't work, but it will fix your issue and make the method more efficient as no temporary set is allocated:

```
public void removeFromContainer(double x, double y) {
    final Point2D loc = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    Iterator<Shape> iter = shapes.keySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (iter.next().contains(loc))
            iter.remove();
    }
}
```

edit: I suspect that you modify the Shape(s) after you add them to the map, so that the hash code when checking for `containsKey` doesn't match the hash code used when adding the Shape to the map.

Comment: +1: Thanks! I prefer avoid the problem by using a List. Using a Map is a mistake here.